# how to control relay with raspberry using pi4j

Tags: java, swing, pi4j

sorry for my english but i recently write code in java about controlling relay by raspberry but my code doesnt work , i used gpio_00 as output the problem is when i initialize it the relay led stay on even when i change stat to low here my code:

```
GpioUtil.enableNonPrivilegedAccess();
 gpioRelayLED2 = GpioFactory.getInstance();          
         relayLED2 = gpioRelayLED2.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_00,"RelayLED2",PinState.LOW);
         //relayLED2.setState(PinState.LOW);
       relayLED2.setShutdownOptions(true, PinState.LOW,PinPullResistance.OFF);
       relayLED2.low();
```

it not turning !!

Answer (score 0):

Some relays are low level triggered. You have to set HIGH output state for such relay to disable LED.

Comment: Thank you but i found where problem was , i had to relate a diod between gpio pin and  input of relay